# Cannot connect to Oracle 19 with unixODBC

Tags: oracle, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 19 database using unixODBC 2.3.7.
I'm using the Oracle Developer Days VirtualBox VM.

When trying to troubleshoot via `isql` I always get this error:

```
# isql -v -3 oracledsn

[HY000][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Sadly I can't reproduce it now, but when last trying it I always had

```
[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

This is the same error message I get from my (proprietary) C++ code, so I'm pretty sure the problem is just the connection settings.

I have checked https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/ but none of the combinations work.

Here are all my config settings:

```
# odbcinst -j                                                                                                                                            -130-

unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/florian/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

```
# cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini

[oraclex]
Description     = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 19
Driver          = /mnt/libsqora.so.19.1
Setup           =
FileUsage       =
CPTimeout       =
CPReuse         =
Driver Logging  = 7

[ODBC]
Trace      = Yes
TraceFile  = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace = Yes
Pooling    = No
DEBUG      = 1
```

```
# cat ~/.odbc.ini 

[oracledsn]
Driver = oraclex
Server = 10.1.6.19
Port = 1521
Uid = system
Pwd = oracle
Database = orclcdb/orcl/"<empty>"
```

ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

I also tried `ServerName`

```
ServerName = //10.1.6.19/orclcdb or //10.1.6.19/orcl
[28000][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Here's the `/tmp/odbc.log`:

```
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044774][__handles.c][460]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x1fd7780
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044854][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
                Entry:
                        Environment = 0x1fd7780
                        Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
                        Value = 0x3
                        StrLen = 0
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044886][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][381]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044914][SQLAllocHandle.c][377]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x1fd7780
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044944][SQLAllocHandle.c][493]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Output Handle = 0x1fd8090
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.044983][SQLConnect.c][3721]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x1fd8090
                        Server Name = [oracledsn][length = 9 (SQL_NTS)]
                        User Name = [NULL]
                        Authentication = [NULL]
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

                DIAG [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist


[ODBC][18832][1564563250.082037][SQLConnect.c][4244]
                Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.082070][SQLGetDiagRec.c][677]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x1fd8090
                        Rec Number = 1
                        SQLState = 0x7fffeabcac60
                        Native = 0x7fffeabcac5c
                        Message Text = 0x7fffeabcac70
                        Buffer Length = 500
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x7fffeabcac5a
[ODBC][18832][1564563250.082092][SQLGetDiagRec.c][726]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        SQLState = HY000
                        Native = 0x7fffeabcac5c -> 12545
                        Message Text = [[unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

I've also been trying out this C code from https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html#connect_full - basically the same result.

```
# cat test2.c
#   compile with gcc -I ../include test2.c -o test2 -lodbc

#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <sql.h>                                                                
#include <sqlext.h>                                                             

/*                                                                              
 * see Retrieving ODBC Diagnostics                                              
 * for a definition of extract_error().                                         
 */                                                                             
static void extract_error(                                                      
    char *fn,                                                                   
    SQLHANDLE handle,                                                           
    SQLSMALLINT type);                                                          

main() {                                                                        
  SQLHENV env;                                                                  
  SQLHDBC dbc;                                                                  
  SQLHSTMT stmt;                                                                
  SQLRETURN ret; /* ODBC API return status */                                   
  SQLCHAR outstr[1024];                                                         
  SQLSMALLINT outstrlen;                                                        

  /* Allocate an environment handle */                                          
  SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);                        
  /* We want ODBC 3 support */                                                  
  SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);          
  /* Allocate a connection handle */                                            
  SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);                                    
  /* Connect to the DSN mydsn */                                                
  ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, "DSN=oracledsn;", SQL_NTS,                  
                         outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen,                    
                         SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);                                  
  if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {                                                     
    printf("Connected\n");                                                      
    printf("Returned connection string was:\n\t%s\n", outstr);                  
    if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {                                         
      printf("Driver reported the following diagnostics\n");                    
      //extract_error("SQLDriverConnect", dbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);                 
    }                                                                           
    SQLDisconnect(dbc);               /* disconnect from driver */              
  } else {                                                                      
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect\n");                                     
    //extract_error("SQLDriverConnect", dbc, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);                   
  }                                                                             
  /* free up allocated handles */                                               
  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc);                                           
  SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, env);                                           
}
```

As another point reference I can connect to said Oracle Dev VM with `sqlplus` from another machine like this:

```
./sqlplus sys/oracle@10.1.6.19/orclcdb as sysdba

SQL>

./sqlplus system/oracle@10.1.6.19/orclcdb

SQL>
```

On the VM I have a file `/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` but I am not completely sure if I also need one on the client?

```
ORCLCDB=localhost:1521/orclcdb
ORCL=
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: U  must have https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html and should properly set some system variebles PS: srr my english

Comment: Yes, I'm using the instant client and I also tried the environment variables like `ORACLE_SID` and `TWO_TASK` like suggested in other similar questions here, but I didn't get any better result.

Comment: set ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN and add folder with dll to PATH, then try to connect from remote client by sqlplus. if work go to tune odbc ...

Comment: more explain ORACLE_HOME= <path to oracle client>, TNS_ADMIN=<path to filder with tnsnames.ora>/ tnsnames shuld content record as on u server. change HOST from 0.0.0.0 to valid IP server's adtress

Comment: I finally found the solution, althoug this is for 12.2.0.1 and not 19

```
# cat .odbc.ini
[oracledsn]                                                                     
Driver=oracle                                                                 
UID=system
PWD=oracle
DBQ=192.168.178.32:1521/ORCLCDB
ServerName=//192.168.178.32:1521/ORCLCDB
```

```
cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
[oracle]
Description = foo
Driver = /mnt/libsqora.so.19.1
Driver Logging = 7
UsageCount=1
FileUsage=1

[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace = Yes
Pooling = No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution, although this is for 12.2.0.1 and not 19

```
# cat .odbc.ini
[oracledsn]                                                                     
Driver=oracle                                                                 
UID=system
PWD=oracle
DBQ=192.168.178.32:1521/ORCLCDB
ServerName=//192.168.178.32:1521/ORCLCDB
```

```
cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
[oracle]
Description = foo
Driver = /mnt/libsqora.so.19.1
Driver Logging = 7
UsageCount=1
FileUsage=1

[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
ForceTrace = Yes
Pooling = No
```

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. isql -v oracledsn system oracle
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
```

I have *no Oracle-specific environment variables set*, but if it works if I take the value of `ServerName` verbatim for `TWO_TASK`.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with oracle 19c, with one minor change here - remove the "//" from ServerName i.e.

```
ServerName=192.168.178.32:1521/ORCLCDB
```